# Evaluate the limit involving summation

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

> Evaluate
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left[\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\right]\left(\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}\right]\right)^{-1}\right)$$ where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

I have no idea how to begin. I can't see any Riemann integration here. I plugged it in wolframalpha but it's time exceeded.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the [Cesàro Mean Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_Mean) to each sum since the terms in each sum approach a constant. Looking at the first sum, we see that

$$\left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}} \to 1$$

as $k\to\infty$. Similarly

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}} \to 1$$

Applying the theorem leads to

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}{\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}} = 1$$

Finally, since each limit is convergent their quotient must also be convergent  implying that

$$\frac{1}{1} = \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}}{\lim_{n\to\infty}{\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{k+1}}}$$